# MKMapView - How to display "No Data" when no coordinates available

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit

How might I get a view with the string "No Data" to show up in a MKMapView when I have no coordinates available to display?

**steve**

Comment: By "no coordinates" do you mean userLocation?  Are you using mapView.showsUserLocation or CLLocationManager to get user location?

Comment: I want to keep the mapview on the screen but I currently have no coordinates to display (I am not displaying the user location).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the map view is full screen, you can put a `UILabel` on top of the map view (***not*** as a subview) and initialize the label's `hidden` property to `NO` (and `text` set to "No Data").

You may also want to set the `alpha` to around 0.5 so the map is still visible underneath.

Set `hidden` to `YES` (or animate the `alpha` to 0.0) when you have coordinates.

Make sure the label doesn't cover up "Google" in the bottom-left.

Comment: That sounds like the ticket (and cool too!).  I'll be honest, I thought there might be a way to tell the mapview to show "No Data" but this will do nicely!  Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

if "data" means pin, ok.
refining answer of "user467105"

Make sure the label doesn't cover up "Legal" in the bottom-left.
(google maps worked 'til iOS5.. now go with Apple!)